# Need to export data in CCR format from Java

Tags: java, xml-serialization, ccr, ccd

I'm working in a project which needs to export EHR information in CCR format. I must use Java. The problem that I'm facing is that I can't find an easy way to do it.

The better way to do what I'm doing would be to export as CDA using something like [CDAPI](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mr/cdapi+user+guide)  but it's overly expensive (30k/year) and complicated. However it shows an example of what I'd like. Something like:

```
CCR ccr = new CCR();
...
out.print(ccr.toString()); // Returns XML
```

But it's as if this doesn't exist.

There's [CCR4J](http://code.google.com/p/ccr4j/) but it can only read XML files and make Java objects. Not the other way around.

There's [Google Health](http://code.google.com/apis/health/) (now discontinued) which *might* have what I'm looking for, but I can't even figure out how to use it.

There's [CCR Binder](https://github.com/giladbu/CCRBinder) which has some convenience methods for creating CCR XML from code built on top of Google Health API, but I can't figure out how to use that either.

I could also just read the [ASTM CCR Spec](http://www.astm.org/Standards/E2369.htm) and implement something on my own which at this point begins to look like the faster option.

Now I would really like to stay away from Google Health. Seems to be an overkill for my task as is exporting do CDA. Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Just for the benefit of people searching for the same info. Here's the [CCR Spec](http://developer.healthvault.com/types/type.aspx?id=1e1ccbfc-a55d-4d91-8940-fa2fbf73c195).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:
[Video: Quick and Dirty CCR](http://www.veoh.com/watch/v15432395RfCdD5ck?h1=Quick+and+Dirty+CCR+XML)

To summarize: Use JAXB to make the classes them marshall them using JAXB marshaller.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for this (very) late answer, but i stumbled uppon this post, cause it's still ranked high in Google if you search for java and CCR. To prevent others from giving up to quick I have to correct you:

**With CCR4J you CAN create CCRs from Java Objects** (since 2008) and it works like a charm! Not just parsing it from a given file.
Perhaps you just didn't got how to use the library back in time?

So here's a little Example (no valid CCR!) for the next one, who stumble over this post trying to create a CCR with this library:

```
//New XML-Document
ContinuityOfCareRecordDocument newDoc = ContinuityOfCareRecordDocument.Factory.newInstance();

//New CCR
ContinuityOfCareRecord newCCR = ContinuityOfCareRecord.Factory.newInstance();

//Add Object ID
newCCR.setCCRDocumentObjectID("asdasdbdffdjg343204dsss3490");

//Add new Language
newCCR.addNewLanguage().setText("English");

//Add new Body
newCCR.addNewBody();

//Add new Problem with Code
newCCR.getBody().addNewProblems().addNewProblem().addNewDescription().addNewCode().setCodingSystem("ICD");
newCCR.getBody().getProblems().getProblemArray(0).getDescription().getCodeArray(0).setValue("1225-55558");

//Add CCR to document and save
newDoc.setContinuityOfCareRecord(newCCR);
newDoc.save(new File("My-Generated-CCR.xml"));
```